# hold-for analogue for distributed jmeter test in taurus

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, taurus

How can be a parameter like hold-for used for concurrent be set up for distributed test in taurus:
Say, I would like

```
execution:
- distributed: 
  - host1.mynet.com
  - host2.mynet.com
  - host3.mynet.com
  scenario: some_scenario
  hold-for: 2m

scenarios:
  some_scenario:
    script: my-test.jmx
```

to have load for 2 minutes only on all nodes disregarding to the test timing in my-test.jmx. How can I do this? Hold-for works for cuncurrency set up only, not for distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading code of Taurus, it looks it would be possible like this:

```
 execution:
   - concurrency: ${__P(my_conc,3)}    # use `my_conc` prop or default=3 if property isn't found
        ramp-up: 30
       hold-for: 2m
       scenario: some_scenario

   - distributed: 
       - host1.mynet.com
       - host2.mynet.com
       - host3.mynet.com

 scenarios:
      some_scenario:
          script: my-test.jmx
```